# Dygraph with non-numeric/non-date x axis

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, dygraphs

How can I use dygraph to create a visualization for data that uses non-numeric/non-date values in the x-axis?

I am trying to do a visualization of budget data with the following javascript pulled from a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf7351c7/3/).

```
g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    "Departments,2012 Actual,2013 Actual\n"+
    "Public Works,100,200\n"+
    "Police,50,150"      ,
    {
        title: 'Fort Lauderdale Budget Data'
    }
);
```

When I try to run it, I get the following errors in the browser javascript debugger console.

> "Couldn't parse Public Works as a date"
>
> "Couldn't parse Police as a date"

I did look at the [axis options](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html) provided in dygraphs, but they seemed to only address formatting the value rather than parsing it. I realize that I could re-orient the axis/data to use a date as the x-axis, but I would prefer to avoid this additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dygraphs assumes that the first column of your data is the independent (x-axis) variable. You might be able to get around this by writing a `DataHandler`, but it will be far easier to reorganize your data to put the year in the first column.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. One wrinkle had to do with x values that didn't exactly correlate to a year. For example, FY 2012 Proposed, FY 2012 Adopted and FY 2012 Amended doesn't fit neatly into this paradigm. Any way to compensate for this outside of the DataHandler? Or is this the wrong tool for the job? 

Can you point me to the documentation for the DataHandler?

Comment: What type of chart are you trying to create? If it's a bar chart or a pie chart, dygraphs isn't a good choice. If you want to draw three distinct lines, you need to model your data as three separate columns (Proposed, Adopted, Amended), rather than as three different types of year.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am interested in representing the information as a line graph, however the issue with making it different columns is that then I would need to have Police Proposed, Police Adopted and Police Amended which becomes unreadable with lots of different categories. The actual data can be found https://fortlauderdalefl.opengov.com/transparency#218. Maybe this is a round peg into a square whole problem at least going across years and proposed/adopted/amended.

Comment: You'll have the same number of values however you organize your data. If you want to display *{Proposed,Adopted,Amended} as something other than separate series, you could try a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html). I'm still unclear how you want to show the three values for each year/item pair.

Comment: I see what you mean. Can you add a reference to the documentation on the DataHandler? Then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Well there is [this](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/410) :) But in the meantime, the best documentation is probably [the source](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/src/datahandler/datahandler.js).

Comment: @danvk I need a scatter plot and have x,y coordinate values which are just simple numbers. No date is needed. Is this possible using dygraphs? Currently, it throws error as failed to parse in date format.